# can anyone help me to write farsi(persion) in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Hi I wana use persion language in eclipse.whenever I press the space the word after that space apears back of previous word and make my text vice versa.

for instanse:
// کلاس اول ==>  this is correct form.

but in eclipse
// اول کلاس ==> I dont want this

Answer (score 0):

`OS default` should be enough but you can try setting `Right to Left` or `Contextual`specifically

[image]